# how to pass user input from HTML form when using express.Router()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a file server.js that looks like so:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Bear = require('./models/bear');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://123:pass123@ds1383.mlab.com:53/bears');


var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = 8080;


var router = express.Router();



router.use(function(req, res, next){

   //console.log("Working....");
   next();

});


router.get('/', function (req, res){

    res.json({ message: "API Works!"});

});


router.route('/bears')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log("hi");

    var bear = new Bear(req.body);      // create a new instance of the Bear model
    console.log(bear);
    // save the bear and check for errors
    bear.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'Bear created!' });
    });

});



app.use("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.use('/books', router);

app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port "+ port);
```

And my Index.html file looks like so:

```
<head> 

</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="/bears">
        Enter Book to add
        <input type="text" id="book_name"/>
        <br /><br />

        Enter Quantity
        <input type="number" id="book_quantity"/>
        <br /><br />

        Enter Price

        <input type="text" id="book_price"/>
        <br /><br />

        <button type="submit"> Add Book </button>


    </form>

</body>
```

I was wondering why it doesn't enter the

```
router.route('/bears')
.post(function(req, res){});
```

when clicking the "Add Book" button even thought I've set the

`action="/bears"`  attribute.

When testing with curl, it works fine, just not with this html form

I test with curl like so:

`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "book_name" : "Android",  "book_quantity": 2,"book_price": 580 }' localhost:8080/books`

I'm new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does happen when you click submit? Do you go to one of the other routes?

Comment: If I use app.post it does. But not with router.route

Comment: Note your curl test is requesting `/books` not `/bears`

Comment: I changed it to action="/books" but no luck. I also tried action="/books/bears", but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

For post call through html form, "name" attributes for all input tags are mandatory

```
<form method="POST" action="/books/bears">
    Enter Book to add
    <input type="text" id="book_name" name="book_name"/>
    <br /><br />

    Enter Quantity
    <input type="number" id="book_quantity" name="book_quantity"/>
    <br /><br />

    Enter Price

    <input type="text" id="book_price" name="book_price"/>
    <br /><br />

    <button type="submit"> Add Book </button>


</form>
```

Also use

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

in server code

This is because form sends post data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format, so access as req.body.book_name in server.

if json format is needed then use javascript on client and make json and then send.

Comment: I fixed it. But it still doesn't enter the post function

Comment: `action="/books/bears"`

Comment: I changed it, but still no luck

Comment: check now @TimalPeramune

Comment: Changed, no luck

Comment: console.log("hi"); => is "hi" not printing in console? @TimalPeramune

Comment: I got it working, appreciate the help! I did not know the name attribute was mandatory in a form

Comment: Note the name attributes are not mandatory for the request itself to be made, they however are mandatory for the input values to be included in the request. Also bodyParser wouldn't prevent the route from being reached it just affects how the body (the input values) of the request is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Is being used for all the requests and not just '/`. Instead use`app.get()` to handle the index.html page. This should then let your requests go through.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

And the endpoint would be `/books/bears` and not just `/bears` since your route use is `app.use('/books',router)` so your endpoints would need to start with `/books`

```
<form method="POST" action="/books/bears">
```

Comment: i changed it to action="/books/bears" and in server.js I changed it to `router.route.get("/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html"); 
});`  but still no luck. Should I be removing something?

Comment: @TimalPeramune Yea the router.route part was wrong, use just `app.get()` you must have seen the post before i removed that part